# Rspec Testing for after_sign_in_path_for(@user) in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, capybara

I have a following after_sign_in_path_for(@user) method in the application controller and this method is protected.

```
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    if current_account.present?
      if current_account.role.present? && current_account.role.downcase == "admin"
        admin_dashboard_path
      elsif current_account.role.present? && current_account.role.downcase == "sales"
        sales_dashboard_path
      elsif current_account.role.present? && current_account.role.downcase == "claims"
        claims_dashboard_path
      else
        admin_dashboard_path
      end
    elsif current_partner.present?
      affiliate_dashboard_path
    elsif current_agent.present?
      agents_dashboard_path
    else
      root_path
    end      
  end
```

How can I write Rspec Testing for above method?

I am using Capybara for Rspec.

Comment: This isn't an answer, but you can write this is much less code: http://pastebin.com/Ge0jZ9Z1

Comment: please optimize that code...its just bad... specially this `current_account.role.present? && current_account.role.downcase`